# WSO2: Ask Password From User when creating user via SCIM Rest Endpoint

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

Is there a way, when creating a WSO2 user via the SCIM REST API, to specify that you want to ask the password from the user instead of setting the password explicitly?

For example, I'm able to succesfully create users via the REST API like so:

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data "{"schemas":[],"name":     {"familyName":"vader","givenName":"darth"},"userName":"dvader@empire.com","password":"myPassword","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"darthvader@empire.com","type":"home"},{"value":"darthvader@tatooine.com","type":"work"}]}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users
```

But instead of explicitly setting the password, I'd like to create a user in this way, but allow the user to set their password.

When adding a user using the WSO2 Management Console, you can select the "Ask password from user" box, so it seems to be possible. I just need to know how to do it via the REST API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"Ask password from user" option comes with the identity management features of the identity server. at the moment (Up to WSO2IS 5.0.0) it is not possible to do this for a user provisioned through SCIM. You will have to give a common password and later users can change it.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 supports ask password feature with SCIM as well. You can use the following request to create a user. Here we do not need to give the password for the user. We need to give the email address of the user because the account confirmation email will be sent to that email address.

curl -k --user admin:admin --data "{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"edirisinghe","givenName":"dushan"},"userName":"edirisinghe", "emails":"thariyarox@gmail.com"}" --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users

You can get to know more about this feature by referring [1].

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2015/07/create-users-with-ask-password-feature.html

Thank you,
Tharindu Edirisinghe